# Firestore Security Rule to allow update nested field

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a document with structure

```
name: "blablabla"
members:
    123: true
    456: true
```

Users can add themselves in `members`

```
docRef.update(FieldPath.of("members", myUid), true);
```

How do I write a security rule to allow this?

---

I tried

```
allow update: if is_valid(request.resource.data);
function is_valid(data) {
  return data.keys() == ['members']
      && data.members.keys() == [request.auth.uid]
      && data.members[request.auth.uid] == true;
}
```

But I get `PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.`

(However in Security Rules Simulator access is allowed)

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a condition using [removedKeys](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.MapDiff#removedKeys). In theory, this should work as it should.

```
allow update: if is_valid(request.resource.data);
function is_valid(data) {
  return data.keys() == ['members']
      && data.members.keys() == [request.auth.uid]
      && afterData().members.diff(resource.data.members).removedKeys().size() == 0;
}  
function afterData() {
  return getAfter(/databases/$(database)/documents).data;
}
```